# How to compute weights using logistic regression

Tags: logistic, survey, weighted-data, survey-sampling, survey-weights

I'm not interested in creating a logistic regression model which is weighted, I'm interested in using a logistic regression model to compute the weights of a survey. It seems that, given the weights are the inverse probability of the respondent being selected, it should be possible to create some logistic regression model in order to compute the weights for the survey given a particular set of statistics.

Here is some example data:

```r
# setup example
set.seed(1)
N=100
w <- runif(N, min = 0.01, max = 2)
w <- N * (w / sum(w))

set.seed(1)
# this is the data that we have. 
sd1 <- rbinom(N, size = 1, prob = 0.5)
sd2 <- rbinom(N, size = 2, p = 0.5)
s_data <- data.frame( s_1 = sd1, s_2 = sd2, weight = w)

# these are the values within the population.
pd1 = setNames(c(0.6, 0.4), c('0', '1'))
pd2 <- setNames(c(0.25, 0.45, 0.3), c('0', '1', '2'))
```

For data such as the above I have seen weights computed as follows:

```r
library(dplyr)
# compute for df1 first
w1 <- dplyr::recode(sd1, `0`=0.6, `1`=0.4)
s_data$w <- w1
# compute for d2
w2 <- dplyr::recode(sd2, `0` = 0.25, `1`=0.45,`2`=0.3)
s_data$w <- w2 * s_data$w
# compute for d3
w3 <- dplyr::recode(sd3, `0`=0.05,`1`=0.2,`2`=0.4,`3`=0.25,`4`=0.1)
s_data$w<-w3 * s_data$w
s_data$w <- N * (s_data$w / sum(s_data$w))
```

*Note - I'm not saying that the above is correct, or that I'm expecting a logistic regression model to reproduce the above exactly, I'm simply providing it for context.*

I feel as though there should be some approach using logistic regression to computing the weights for this data, given the national values which are expected and the observed data, but I'm currently unsure how this would be done and am unable to find any literature on it.

Note - this is not an R question, though if the answer uses R that's fine.